# Why jQuery animate(width) not working for modal box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using a modal box in my page as follows:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 10%;
    position: relative;
}
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Javascript jQuery code:

```
$(window).on('load',async function() {
$('#myModal').fadeIn(1500);
    $('#modal-content').animate({'width': "40%"});
    $('.close').on('click', async function() {
        $('#myModal').slideUp();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zojaji/u37Lc6m0/)

But unfortunately `animate` code is not working and finally width of `modal-cntent` is 10% in the browser inspect.

1- Can anyone solve the problem?

2: Is there a best way to pop the box?

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: @Vel Fiddle added.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

You need to use class `.modal-content` not id `#modal-content`

```
$(window).on('load',async function() {
    $('#myModal').fadeIn(1500);
    $('.modal-content').animate({width: "40%"});
    $('.close').on('click', async function() {
        $('#myModal').slideUp();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wjfnezh/1/)

Comment: Please add attribute id in 'modal-content'

Comment: There is no Id in you html.